# error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

profile.component.ts:

```
var $inputs = $('#changePasswordForm :input');
    var values = {
      oldpassword: String,
      newpassword: String
    };
    $inputs.each(function() {
      console.log(this);
      values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(values.oldpassword, this.currentUser.username);
```

profile.component.html:

```
<form id='changePasswordForm'>
            <div class='form-group input-field'>
              <label for=''>Old Password*</label>
              <input type='password' [(ngModel)]='oldpassword' name='oldpassword' class='form-control'>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group input-field'>
              <label for=''>New Password*</label>
              <input type='password' [(ngModel)]='newpassword' name='newpassword' class='form-control'>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Error:

ERROR in src/app/components/profile/profile.component.ts(82,19): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

What did i go wrong ??

Comment: Do you need `HTMLInputElement` instead?

Comment: well, my question is why you are using jquery in angular application because it considers a bad approach.

Comment: Actually application is considering the Angular `this` instead of the `jQuery` so it is looking for the HTML biding for that. Ideally you should not mixed up, Angular & Jquery. It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Try not to use JQuery in Angular

You can do your code like this in Angular(ngx).
Your are using `ngModel` so it is two way binding, you can access this values in you component file.

HTML

```
<form id='changePasswordForm' (ngSubmit)="changePass()">
            <div class='form-group input-field'>
              <label for=''>Old Password*</label>
              <input type='password' [(ngModel)]='oldpassword' name='oldpassword' class='form-control'>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group input-field'>
              <label for=''>New Password*</label>
              <input type='password' [(ngModel)]='newpassword' name='newpassword' class='form-control'>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Change Password</button>
</form>
```

TS (Component)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  oldpassword: string;
  newpassword: string;

  changePass() {

// Here we are getting and setting values
    const values = {
        oldpassword: this.oldpassword,
        newpassword: this.newpassword
    };

    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-change-password-demo

Comment: Note that OP is trying to console.log `this.currentUser.username` too (whereever that comes from).

Comment: yes,  `this.currentUser.username` this must be coming from some other variable.
I am just trying to help him with the angular way rather than using JQuery,